# Why does Pandas get_dummies function not also perform a 'pivot'?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Customer      Product
   A           Table
   A           Chair
   A           Desk
```

and when I run the Pandas get_dummies function on Product, I get this:

```
Customer   Product_Table    Product_Chair    Product_Desk
   A             1                 0                0 
   A             0                 1                0
   A             0                 0                1
```

Is this correct in terms of pre-modeling?  It would seem that I'm feeding it customer A information 3 different times.  The first time I'm saying it only has Table and no chairs or desk, but in reality they have all three.

How does this affect the model?  My gut tells me that when I do this type of conversion I should end up with only 1 line?  Is that right?  And if so, what did I do wrong, or need to add, in order to eliminate the 'duplicate' rows?

Below is the syntax I'm using:

```
# Create a list of features to dummy
todummy_list = []
for col_name in sdf.columns:
    if sdf[col_name].dtypes == 'object' and (col_name != 'Customer' ):
        todummy_list.append(col_name)
print(todummy_list)


# Function to dummy all the categorical variables used for modeling
def dummy_df(df, todummy_list):
    for x in todummy_list:
        dummies = pd.get_dummies(sdf[x], prefix=x, dummy_na=False)
        df = df.drop(x, 1)
        df = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)
    return df

sdf = dummy_df(sdf, todummy_list)

print(sdf.head(5))
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the get_dummies? The purpose of the function is to [one-hot encode](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f) the column, not to tie the column back to a single customer. Are you trying to do a `groupby('customer').count()`?

Comment: I'm trying to convert categorical data to numeric to be used as a feature.  And when just experimenting with this (I'm new to ML) I would have expected the model to prefer just the one line with new binary columns, not 3.  So I guess I'm not sure if I need the grouping or if the models would be fine with the 3 lines?

Comment: Simply put, you should probably not be one-hot encoding this data as it is now. From what I understand of your data (which is admittedly not much), you need to do more feature engineering before you get to this step. If all of the types of furniture are tied to a single record, your columns should look more like `customer|ordered_table?|ordered_chair?|ordered_desk?|...` and then cust A would look like `A|1|1|1`, then the next row would look maybe like `B|0|1|0`

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct!  Not sure why I was making it so hard, but the no model would be very effective if I'm constantly feeding it contradictory information about the same customer.  I also realized I can aggregate the dummied dataframe to give me a single row per customer.

Comment: A pivot would include an aggregate would it not?  Also a true pivot would aggregate values vs getdummies would only give you binary representations.  In specific examples the output of getdummies + aggregate may be the same as a pivot but they are doing different things and are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate the "duplicate rows", you can just use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
res = pd.crosstab(df['Customer'], df['Product'])

print(res)

Product   Chair  Desk  Table
Customer                    
A             1     1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

The list you created is empty. You need to fill it up for example:

```
todummy_list = ['age','sex','working-class']
```